# How to enable Write-Ahead Log(WAL) journal mode for SQLite in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, wal

I want to enable WAL mode for journal_mode. I'm using the **class SqliteDatabase** of **CIPHER package**. It does not have a **`enableWriteAheadLogging()`** method. And instead of that I tried to enable the mode through transactions.

But there was an exception that `"Caused by: net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: cannot change into wal mode from within a transaction: PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL".` I don't have no variants to solve it. Help me, please!

Comment: Just like the error says, you can't use that pragma in a transaction. So run it when not in a transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to enable wal mode through `SQLiteDatabaseHook::postKey` while opening database. In the `postKey()` method need to execute `database.rawExecSQL("PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL");` command.

Comment: Or `database.enableWriteAheadLogging();`